# ModalView on the top of UITabBarController during app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I'm a bit lost trying to figure it out...

I have a tab bar based app with login screen at the start. Login screen should be done as Modal View Controller BEFORE tab bar controller appears.

The problem is that I can present it only in `viewDidAppear:` method of TabBarController. And user can see for half a second content of the `UITabBarController`. I've tried to move call to `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` but it logs an error in console: "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". As far as I can understand you can only add ModalViewController when all child `UIViewControllers` of `UITabBarController` are loaded, ad that happens in `viewDidAppear:` delegate method.

Do you have any solution how to show login screen without showing TabBarController before?

I've tried 2 ways of displaying ModalViewController, both of them work in `viewDidAppear:` only

1. XIB file with login view and using `presentViewController:` code

   ```
   self.loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentViewController:self.loginController animated:NO completion:nil];
   ```
2. Storyboard, modal segue and calling it from the code:

   ```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen" sender:self];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a modal, you might consider pushing the login screen onto a navigation stack. Inside `viewWillAppear:` you can just instantiate your login viewController and push it. You could also do it in `viewDidLoad` if you'd like.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourInstantiatedLoginViewController animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: I considered that but, I have couple issues in that case:

1. It will have push animation (I know it is possible to change it)
2. I feel it is just not logically right to do that.. View flow will be not really logical.

So I'd prefer to find a way to do that using ModalViewController.

Comment: Yeah, totally get that. As for #1 though, taking over on the UINavigationControllerDelegate and setting a custom animation is pretty straightforward, and will allow you to create the same exact animation/dismissal you get from modal presentations. I agree with #2, but its probably debatable. I guess you could also consider having the loginViewController set as a childViewController and animating the presentation/dismissal of the child subview yourself. The nav stack seems a ton cleaner to me though. Just a couple thoughts.